# Why do List<T>, Dictionary<T> and others collections contain a field called "version"?

Tags: c#, .net

I was looking at the source code reference for C# and in some collections I found:

```
int _version = 0;
```

Each time the collection changes the version increases.

**Whats the point of that field?**

[Dictionary](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0)

[List](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

[Stack](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6)

Comment: Do you have an example of where this code is?

Comment: It should help your understanding if you would look at **all** usages of `_version` by List<T> (for example) in the reference source code. In short, it appears to be used to detect concurrent modifications on the collection while some method/enumerator of the collection is executing/active.

Comment: My guess it's used for some kind of dirty flag to know when the collection has changed and help to understand when to fire registered callbacks.

Comment: It is a crucial field in order to generate the InvalidOperationException, "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".  The iterator pays attention to it, when the *version* changed then it knows that continuing to iterate is a Very Big Problem.

Comment: I **don't agree** that this question is *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: To @elgonzo's point, since you're already looking at the source code, why not look beyond the declaration of that field and see how/where it's used, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L1173) it seems to be used to check if the state has changed and causes the internal `Enumerator` to throw an `InvalidOperationException` when enumerating. This also applies to the `List<T>.ForEach(..)` method.

This makes sense because it's not legal to modify collections while they are being enumerated. More accurately, it's not legal to continue to iterate a collection once it's been modified, but I find the former rule saves me from running into the latter.